# Android Service design - start with activity or only when needed?

Tags: android

I'm an android noob that is looking for some advice on how to properly use a service in Android. I am building an app that will connect to a server on the Internet to get a data stream via TCP. That data then needs to get send out to another device that is connected via a bluetooth serial port. I want this to continue to function in the background while the user looks at a different activity.

The app will be a NTRIP client, which pulls real time RTK correction data from the Internet and sends it to a RTK GPS receiver that I connect to via bluetooth. The data rate will be about 500 bytes/second. The user interface is a single button to connect or disconnect the data stream and some text to show status of the GPS receiver. There are also a few settings that will need to be configured by the user such as the IP/port of the server to connect to and the bluetooth device to communicate with.

I think I need to have the main activity spawn a local service, and then have the service spawn a thread for the TCP stream and another thread for the bluetooth connection. Does this sound right?

What is the best model for the service in this scenario?

-Start(bind) the service every time the activity starts, and have the connect/disconnect button send commands to the service to start/stop the threads. If I go this route, the service will continue to run after the user disconnects and goes to another app. The service would need an inactivity timer to terminate itself.

-Start and stop the service when the user presses the connect/disconnect button. The service only runs when data is moving. If I do this, the activity will need to see if the service is running when the activity starts, in order to know if it should bind to the service or tell the user that the link is disconnected.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with your second option. Checking if a service is running or not is an easy task and also you won't consume unnecessary processing time which will be better for the battery life.

Just because you can run a service for a long time in the background doesn't necessarily mean that you also should do that. At least not all the time.

Answer (score 0):

As android supports more than one entry point into the app, you could define two entry points in the Manifest.xml.

`<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` defines, that this class could be started from the launcher. I guess that would work for a service, too. I would do two entry points. One which spawns the activity first and gives the user some configuration control. And another which simply spawns the service.

As you have no control over the lifetime of an activity i would not suggest to do anything which should not be ended by the system. If you have an incoming call your activity would simply die.
If the user starts the service you could create an widget with the button. If the user starts the activity you could start the service and the widget.
And if the user starts the widget, the user decides, what should happen with the service.

Comment: Partially wrong and the other part is totally confusing and not clear maybe even wrong too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Java or Android programmer so take what I say with a grain of salt.  The normal way to handle blocking IO in Java is to use threads.  It sounds like the data flow is unidirectional but for maximum flexibility I would create 3 threads, one for the UI, one for the TCP connection and one for the bluetooth connection.  Communication between the UI and two worker threads could be done using shared variables (need to careful about synchronization, race conditions, etc).  I would pass the data NTRIP data to the other worker using a multi-threaded queue data structure.

The worker thread for the NTRIP data would be roughly:

```
while (app running) {
   if (connection enabled) {
       if (not connected) {
         c = connect to remote
       }
       data = get data from c
       queue.put(data)
       if (options reconfigured) {
         close c
       }
    }
}
```

For the bluetooth thread:

```
while (app runnning) {
     data = queue.get()
     if (UI settings changed and connected) {
         close connection
     }
     if (not connected) {
         c = connect to remote
     }
     send data over connection
}
```

In the normal state, both workers are blocking on IO and will be consuming essentially no CPU time.  Based on my experience, I would recommend you write your code to handle communication errors.  For your code to work well in the real world you have to handle connections closing, hanging, etc.  Making it robust will likely be the most time consuming part of the development.